# Which of the following is better for performance: Using SQL Order By or Using Linq After data has been loaded?

Tags: c#, sql, performance, linq, query-optimization

I have a simple Users table that I am querying to get a list of all the users that have signed up to my platform. Over the past few days, I noticed that my query is starting to take very long.

I did some research to see why it's taking so long and I read that Order by might be a possible cause. When I removed it, it did improve the performance. So it made me wonder.

Is it better to exclude order by in all my future queries and just use LINQ to order the objects?

Comment: You don't say where you removed it from - the database side or client side?

Comment: in most of the cases, you can use the pagination, I mean get 100, or 1000 records everytime, if you don't need whole data to process in a single shot

Comment: I use database stored procedures to query my data. I removed it from the proc and it reduced execution time by almost 20 seconds.

Comment: @EmilevRooyen usually, databases are pretty nifty when it comes to sorting stuff. _if_ you have proper indizes on your columns, which is the first thing you should evaluate.

Comment: sorting data is expensive and most often will benefit from a suitable index. Usually it's better to sort in the database, especially if you need a subset of rows, as usual ymmv.

Comment: @viveknuna Rowset Pagination still means all previous rows need to be read, and wothout a good index the whole set needs to be sorted also

Answer (score 4):

You are really asking whether it is better to do the ordering on the server or on the local computer.

In general, it is better to let the database do the work, because in general, the database is running on a server that is more powerful than the local machine.  In addition, the database server can decide to use an index for the ordering.  Or, ordering may not be necessary depending on what else happens in the query.

In some cases, doing an `order by` on the server is mandatory.  If you are selecting only a handful of the "top" rows, you need to order on the server.  And, returning all the data (much less ordering it locally) incurs a lot of overhead.

That said, ordering on the server does use resources on the server.  And, there may be situations where you find that on your data and with your queries that local sorting is better.  If that is the case, you can definitely sort locally.  But the expectation would be that sorting on the server is generally the better approach.

Comment: I agree that Order by is required when I want to see specific data. But there are some cases where I want to load all data for batch processing. This is where it made me wonder if for queries where I want to load all data if it wouldn't be better to order them using LINQ instead.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that my processing service is running on the same server as the database.